# IIS7 Url rewriting without code modification

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am looking in to implementing Url rewriting for our site, using the rewrite module 2.0.
currently our urls look like: http://www.example.com/NewChannels/Channel.aspx?ChannelId=4
I want to make this in to http://www.example.com/4/

I got this working, but since many things on the page (background colors, font colors, etc.) use the querystring, they break.
I don`t want to go into the code and change these to use the special server variables. Is there any way of implementing this that does not require code modification?

Comment: Add a rule in queue to not modify the urls containing .css,.jpg stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two simple ways to get it, Use the urlrewrite module or develop your module to do this as you wish.

take a look to this Link for Urlrewrite Module: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Creating your own module, pay attention to thins method: httpapplication.Context.RewritePath

Comment: I`m already using the rewrite module 2.0, as stated at the top of the post :)